# Why does JSTL output a double value of 99 as 99.0 (not 99.00) using ${dollarAmount}?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have a `double` value `dollarAmount` which has the value `99`:

```
double dollarAmount = 99;
```

When I try to output it to my page using this code:

```
<c:out value="${dollarAmount}"/>
```

It comes out as `99.0`.

Because it represents a financial value, I want to output it either as

```
99
```

or as

```
99.00
```

Is there some way to force `<c:out>` to do this?

Answer (score 4):

> *Why does JSTL output a double value of 99 as 99.0*

When printing backend data to HTML response, all non-String java objects are by default converted to `String`. HTML can namely not be represented on other way. You're seeing `99.0`, because that's the default result of [`Double#toString(double)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString%28double%29). The formatting is as per the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString%28double%29).

To format currencies, better use [`<fmt formatNumber>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/formatNumber.html) whose `type` is set to `currency`.

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${dollarAmount}" type="currency" currencySymbol="$" />
```

It'll show up as

```
$99.00
```

Answer (score 2):

i suggest the use of FormatNumber tag [fmt](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/formatNumber.html)

something like

```
<fmt:formatNumber type="number" maxIntegerDigits="2" value="${param.num}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use    [`fmt:formatNumber`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/formatNumber.html)

Answer (score 0):

In java the best way to print out specific amounts of digits is `printf`, a third-party utility from https://sharkysoft.com/ available under the GNU GPL, or for a fee for commercial use. Here is the JavaDoc page: http://sharkysoft.com/archive/printf/docs/javadocs/lava/clib/stdio/doc-files/specification.htm

Comment: The OP is using JSP/JSTL. You really don't want to mingle raw Java code in there.